# Elastic search - How to Handle Relationship between two documents

Tags: elasticsearch

I've the follow documents:

```
{"id":1 , "user_id":1234, "tags":["b"]}
{"id":2 , "user_id":1234, "tags":["a"]}
{"id":3 , "user_id":1236, "tags":["b"]}
{"id":4 , "user_id":1237, "tags":["b"]}
{"id":5 , "user_id":1238, "tags":["a"]}
{"id":6 , "user_id":1239, "tags":["b"]}
```

And i want get all users_id that haven't "a" in "tags".

```
1236,(id =3 ) 
1237,(id =4 ) 
1239,(id =6 )
```

And i don't want to get 1234,(id=1), be cause he has "a" in "tags" in another document.
I tried to handle this with aggregations (searching and trying) but can't resolve.

Do you know how to resolve this?
Thank for read.
Best Regards!! :)
PS: I use java api to query my data, but you feel free to use DSL (json).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this problem is probably to take advantage of the [parent/child relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html).

To test it out, I set up an index with two mappings, one for the parent type `"user"` and one for the child type `"user_tag"`:

```
PUT /test_index
{
   "mappings": {
      "user": {
         "_id": {
            "path": "user_id"
         },
         "properties": {
            "user_id": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      },
      "user_tag": {
         "_parent": {
            "type": "user"
         },
         "properties": {
            "tags": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Then I translated the data you provided into this format (you may have to stare at it a little to convince yourself that this is the same data):

```
POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":1234}
{"index":{"_type":"user_tag","_parent":1234,"_id":1}}
{"tags":["b"]}
{"index":{"_type":"user_tag","_parent":1234,"_id":2}}
{"tags":["a"]}
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":1236}
{"index":{"_type":"user_tag","_parent":1236,"_id":3}}
{"tags":["b"]}
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":1237}
{"index":{"_type":"user_tag","_parent":1237,"_id":4}}
{"tags":["b"]}
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":1238}
{"index":{"_type":"user_tag","_parent":1238,"_id":5}}
{"tags":["a"]}
{"index":{"_type":"user"}}
{"user_id":1239}
{"index":{"_type":"user_tag","_parent":1239,"_id":6}}
{"tags":["b"]}
```

Now I can get the users who do not have a child containing the tag `"a"` with the following query:

```
POST /test_index/user/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "not": {
               "filter": {
                  "has_child": {
                     "type": "user_tag",
                     "filter": {
                        "term": {
                           "tags": "a"
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

which returns:

```
{
   "took": 3,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1236",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "user_id": 1236
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1237",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "user_id": 1237
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "user",
            "_id": "1239",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
               "user_id": 1239
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here's all the code I used:

http://sense.qbox.io/gist/66ca479e994d54257ec8cea86a5acf621a5c8c06